# how to debug on panasonic g1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8.1

I have got this device http://business.panasonic.it/soluzioni-per-computer/toughpad/fz-g1

I have to develop one app on it but I dont know how to debug it because it does not have a micro usb port (but just a usb).

Is there another way to debug it?

Should it work if I buy an adapter microusb to usb so that I can debug using Visual Studio as I did with a Windows Phone or with and Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help someone else in future.

The way to go is remote debug:

1. your development PC and the remote device (where you deploy the app) have to be on the same network.
2. according to Microsoft, PC and device should be connected via Ethernet cable (on ethernet to usb if not present). For me, it work also via WIFI, which is the way I am doing it.
3. Installing the remote debugging components on a remote device (download from the link below)
4. Starting the remote debugger monitor (listed in your apps)
5. use the remote debugger Configuration wizard (listed in your apps)
6. on your PC, debug on remote (after setting the IP address of your remote device)

Find more info and download link on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441469.aspx)